# QGIS export vector as CSV with Decimal Degrees (not Meters)

Tags: qgis, export, csv

I am trying to convert a Satellite JP2 file to a CSV database showing the lat/lon and a column with a calculated NDVI value. Both my project CRS and layer CRS are set to EPSG::28992. I have done the following:

1. Add raster layer with the JP2
2. Use the raster calculator to calculate NDVI index
3. Use the Raster value's to points tool in the Processing Toolbox

When step 3 is completed the Identify Results panel is no longer showing the coordinates in Decimal Degrees but in meters (except for the values under '(Derived)'. The current map coordinates are still shown in Decimal Degrees. When saving the shapefile to CSV it's only possible to choose XY in meters.

Is there a way to export lat/lon coordinates?

[image: screenshot identify results panel]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EPSG 28992 has a plane coordinate system (stereographic projection). To see WGS84 (EPSG 4326) latitude, longitude you should change the projection of map canvas to EPSG 5326 and enable on the fly reprojection (OTF). On your screen shot I see OTF is on, so click the icon in front of EPSG 28992 and change to EPSG 4326. If you want not only see WGS84 coordinates, but store these coordinates in your layer, than select Save As from the pop up menu of the layer and change the projection to EPSG 4326.

Comment: Changing the projection of the map to EPSG:4326 and then saving the layer as CSV worked. With the changed projection it's also possible to add a lat/lon attribute using the field calculator (using the $x and $y expression) in the layer properties. Many thanks for the comments!

Comment: Please think of accepting the answer since it seems to work for you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers